# node.js token deletion promise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

I have a delete route for my api that deletes tokens stored in our mongodb. I am currently writing a check that makes sure the token is not associated with another object before it is processed for deletion.

```
function checkTokenIsNotUsed(req) {
  console.log('TEST ' + req.params.token);
  objectDB.findObject('artefact', {"data.token": req.params.token})
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log('findObject result' + result);
    if (isDefined(result)) {
      console.log('Artefact Exists');
      serverError(res, 'Cannot delete token as it is associated with an artefact');
    } else {
      console.log('Token not being used by an artefact, okay for deletion');
    };
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.error('Token CHECK DELETE error: '+err.message);
    serverError(res, 'err.message');
  });
return(result)
};
//
// Token deletion
//
app.delete('/:token', function(req, res, next) {
  checkTokenIsNotUsed(req)
  .then(function(results){
    return tokenModel.findOne({token: req.params.token});
  })
```

As it stands, when I hit the route the `checkTokenIsNotUsed` function is called, and prints `'TEST + <token>'` to the console, and then kicks out to `cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

I have checked my query in the mongo shell independently of the platform interface that I am using and the query works as expected. The api route also works as expected without the `checkTokenIsUsed` function active.

Any ideas as to why the promise for `objectdb.findObject()` is not returning a result? It is intended to return a list of objects or nothing at all, and does as expected in other locations in this file.

-`findObject` is properly exported + imported from its respective location

-the query is correctly structured and works in mongo shell.

-the token itself is being printed just before this function is run, so `checkTokenIsNotUsed` is getting called and being executed.

-I don't really care that the conditional is just printing to the console at the moment, as my objective right now is to merely enter into that part of the function.

EDIT added

```
findObject = function(objType, query, options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    var populateOptions;
    var findQuery = {};
    var findOptions = {
      sort: 'metaData.createTS',
      page: 1,
      limit: 50
    };

    var objectDef = getObjectDef(objType);
    if (!isDefined(objectDef)) return resolve(null);

    // Make sure query exists and has objType set
    if (isDefined(query)) findQuery = query;
    if (!isDefined(findQuery.objType)) findQuery.objType = objType;
    if (isDefined(options)) {
      if (isDefined(options.sort))  findOptions.sort   = options.sort;
      if (isDefined(options.page))  findOptions.page   = toInt(options.page);
      if (isDefined(options.limit)) findOptions.limit  = toInt(options.limit);
    }

    if (isDefined(objectDef.populate)) populateOptions = objectDef.populate;
    else                               populateOptions = "";
    objectDef.model.find(findQuery, null, findOptions)
    .populate(populateOptions)
    .exec(function(error, list) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve(list);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: `function checkTokenIsNotUsed` doesn't return a promise

Comment: what is the purpose of this part `.then(function(results){
    return tokenModel.findOne({token: req.params.token});
  })`? where the result of filndOne should be used?

Comment: it'll be helpful to see the method `findObject` for model `objectDB`. I guess it doesn't return a promise

Comment: Interesting. I added `return(result)` to the end of `checkTokenIsNotUsed`, and now `result` is undefined. Progress from `.then`.

Comment: you should add it before `objectDB.findObject`: `return objectDB.findObject`

Comment: Got it. Now once it hits that query it does not show any errors (progress!), but is hanging in a loop where it prints the `TEST` every 10 seconds and does not move on to get itself out of the `checkTokenIsUsed` function.